# Spring: migrate XML config to Annotation for util:map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have the below *Spring* configuration in an XML file:

```
<util:map id="myService">
    <entry key="s1" value-ref="goodService" />
    <entry key="s2" value-ref="betterService" />
</util:map>
```

is there a way to migrate this to Annotation based configuration, i.e.

```
@Bean
public Map<String, MyService> serviceMap() {
    Map<String, MyService> map = new HashMap<>();
    ...
```

So the *values* in the *Map* are references to beans.

Answer (score 2):

In the config class autowire the instances and place the properties to the map

```
@Autowired
private GoodService goodService;
@Autowired
private BetterService betterService;

@Bean
public Map<String, MyService> serviceMap() {
    Map<String, MyService> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("s1", goodService);
    map.put("s2", betterService);
```